# Removing things from lists in Python

Tags: python, list

When I run this program, I would like it to remove whatever number has been chosen, and not make it reappear the next time it loops through the code, however when it loops through the code for a second time it completely forgets about removing the number from the first time.
Please help (sorry I'm not great at explaining)

part with problem

```
while Play_game == True:

# play the game

colour = ["Red", "Yellow", "Black"]

# create the colour and number for player 1
number_R_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
number_Y_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
number_B_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
colour_p_1 = random.choice(colour)

if colour_p_1 == "Red":
    number_p_1 = random.choice(number_R_1)
    number_R_1.remove(number_p_1)

elif colour_p_1 == "Yellow":
    number_p_1 = random.choice(number_Y_1)
    number_Y_1.remove(number_p_1)

elif colour_p_1 == "Black":
    number_p_1 = random.choice(number_B_1)
    number_B_1.remove(number_p_1)

# create the colour and number for player 2

colour_p_2 = random.choice(colour)

number_R_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
number_Y_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
number_B_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

if colour_p_2 == "Red":
    number_p_2 = random.choice(number_R_2)
    number_R_2.remove(number_p_2)

elif colour_p_2 == "Yellow":
    number_p_2 = random.choice(number_Y_2)
    number_Y_2.remove(number_p_2)

elif colour_p_2 == "Black":
    number_p_2 = random.choice(number_B_2)
    number_B_2.remove(number_p_2)

input("{0} press enter to pick up a card".format(user_1))
print("{0}'s draw : ".format(user_1))
player_1_colour = print(colour_p_1)
player_1_number = print(number_p_1)

input("{0} press enter to pick up a card".format(user_2))
print("{0}'s draw : ".format(user_2))
player_2_colour = print(colour_p_2)
player_2_number = print(number_p_2)
```

full code

```
# Card Game

# modules needed
import random
import time

# introduce the players to the game and the rules


Rules = True
Authenticate = False
Play_game = False

while Rules == True:
print("Hello and welcome to the Card Game, in this game there are 3 rules.")
time.sleep(4)
print("Rule number one: Each player takes their turn to take a card from the draw pile")
time.sleep(5)
print("Rule number two: There are 3 different coloured cards you could have collected as well as "
      "30 different numbers,if both players gain the same colour who ever has the highest number wins "
      "if you don't have the same colour then this is how it will work:")
time.sleep(10)
print(" ")
print("card  | card  | winner")
print("----------------------")
print("Red   | Black | Red")
print("----------------------")
print("Yellow|  Red  | Yellow")
print("----------------------")
print("Black | Yellow| Black")
print(" ")
print("Rule number three: You will play until there are no cards left in the deck, who ever has the most 
cards win, good luck!")
print(" ")

#give the user an option of play, rules or exit

options = input("Would you like to play, exit or read the rules again? (type play, exit, rules) : ")

if options == "rules" or options == "Rules":
    Rules = True
elif options == "exit" or options == "Exit":
    exit()

elif options == "play" or options == "Play":
    Rules = False
    Authenticate = True

else:
    print("Sorry this was not an option (you can only choose play, exit or rules)")

#Get the players names
user_1 = input("Before we begin, what is your name user 1? :")
print("You have a very nice name {0}".format(user_1))
user_2 = input("What is your name user 2? :")
print("you also have a very nice name {0}".format(user_2))

while Authenticate == True:

#authenticate the user

Authentication = input("Have you already created an account? (Yes or No) : ")
if Authentication == "yes" or Authentication == "Yes":
    Play_game = True
    Authenticate = False
elif Authentication == "no" or Authentication == "No":
    print("sorry this isnt completed yet please type Yes")
else:
    print("This was not an option the only options were Yes or No!")


number_R_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
number_Y_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
number_B_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

while Play_game == True:

# play the game

colour = ["Red", "Yellow", "Black"]

# create the colour and number for player 1
number_R_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
number_Y_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
number_B_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
colour_p_1 = random.choice(colour)

if colour_p_1 == "Red":
    number_p_1 = random.choice(number_R_1)
    number_R_1.remove(number_p_1)

elif colour_p_1 == "Yellow":
    number_p_1 = random.choice(number_Y_1)
    number_Y_1.remove(number_p_1)

elif colour_p_1 == "Black":
    number_p_1 = random.choice(number_B_1)
    number_B_1.remove(number_p_1)

# create the colour and number for player 2

colour_p_2 = random.choice(colour)

if colour_p_2 == "Red":
    number_p_2 = random.choice(number_R_2)
    number_R_2.remove(number_p_2)

elif colour_p_2 == "Yellow":
    number_p_2 = random.choice(number_Y_2)
    number_Y_2.remove(number_p_2)

elif colour_p_2 == "Black":
    number_p_2 = random.choice(number_B_2)
    number_B_2.remove(number_p_2)

input("{0} press enter to pick up a card".format(user_1))
print("{0}'s draw : ".format(user_1))
player_1_colour = print(colour_p_1)
player_1_number = print(number_p_1)

input("{0} press enter to pick up a card".format(user_2))
print("{0}'s draw : ".format(user_2))
player_2_colour = print(colour_p_2)
player_2_number = print(number_p_2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when it loops through the code"?  There isn't a loop here.

Comment: "however when it loops through the code for a second time it completely forgets about removing the number from the first time" - there is no second time in your code. it runs once only.

Comment: Hi @0108Ben, can you post the full code? We cannot see any iteration there and it is an important part of your problem.

Comment: If you want the values in your lists to persist between two independent executions of your script, you'll need to read/write that information somewhere that persists after the script ends (e.g. a text file). Then you can read the current values from the file at the start of the script, and then write the updated values back into the file at the end.

Comment: If you are running it in a loop, define your lists outside the loop.

Comment: thanks everyone for your help! @SayandipDutta that seems to have fixed it, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can do the random sampling first, then use the shuffled samples in the loop as follows:

```
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Play_game = True
    # create the colour and number for player 1
    number_R_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
    number_Y_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
    number_B_1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

    n_R = len(number_R_1)
    n_Y = len(number_Y_1)
    n_B = len(number_B_1)
    sample_R_1 = random.sample(number_R_1, n_R)
    sample_Y_1 = random.sample(number_Y_1, n_Y)
    sample_B_1 = random.sample(number_B_1, n_B)
    colour = ["Red", "Yellow", "Black"]
    R_id = 0
    Y_id = 0
    B_id = 0
    # play the game
    while Play_game == True:
        colour_p_1 = random.choice(colour)
        
        if colour_p_1 == "Red":
            number_p_1 = sample_R_1[R_id]
            R_id += 1
        elif colour_p_1 == "Yellow":
            number_p_1 = sample_Y_1[Y_id]
            Y_id += 1
        elif colour_p_1 == "Black":
            number_p_1 = sample_B_1[B_id]
            B_id += 1
#         input("press enter to pick up a card")
        player_1_colour = colour_p_1
        player_1_number = number_p_1
        print(f"Player1: {player_1_colour}, {player_1_number}")
        
        if R_id == n_R:
            colour.remove("Red")
            R_id += 1
        if Y_id == n_Y:
            colour.remove("Yellow")
            Y_id = 1
        if B_id == n_B:
            colour.remove("Black")
            B_id += 1
        if 0 == len(colour):
            break
```

Result:

```
Player1: Red, 4
Player1: Red, 5
Player1: Black, 4
Player1: Red, 8
Player1: Red, 2
Player1: Black, 8
Player1: Yellow, 8
Player1: Black, 1
Player1: Black, 9
Player1: Yellow, 2
Player1: Red, 10
Player1: Black, 10
Player1: Black, 5
Player1: Black, 7
Player1: Black, 2
Player1: Red, 6
Player1: Red, 1
Player1: Yellow, 5
Player1: Black, 3
Player1: Black, 6
Player1: Red, 7
Player1: Red, 9
Player1: Yellow, 9
Player1: Red, 3
Player1: Yellow, 4
Player1: Yellow, 10
Player1: Yellow, 7
Player1: Yellow, 3
Player1: Yellow, 6
Player1: Yellow, 1
```

I commented out the `input` function to show a full run.